# Checkbox does not show after changing font

Tags: java, android

Hello I have a problem with displaying checkbox in alert dialog. It concern only a situation when the font is changed. On Arial everything (title , message and checkbox) shows correctly but on Ginger (`AppThemeWithCustomFont`) this Checkbox not shows at all (title and message works fine). Those are my codes.

checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/skip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:buttonTint="#fff"
    app:buttonTint="#fff"
    android:text="@string/checkbox_show"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>
```

StageZero.java

```
void configureInitDialog() {
AlertDialog adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MojStyl).create();
View checkboxLayout = View.inflate(this, R.layout.checkbox, null);

skip = checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.skip);
adb.setView(checkboxLayout);
adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
adb.setTitle("Info");
adb.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.stage_zero_dialog));
adb.setCancelable(false);
adb.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Ok", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
    String checkBoxResult = "";

    if (skip.isChecked())
        checkBoxResult = "linia2";

    if (checkBoxResult.equals("linia2"))
        editor.putBoolean("hideDialog", true).apply();

});

if (!hideDialog)
    adb.show();
}
```

styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppThemeWithClassicFont" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activity_background</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/arial</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppThemeWithCustomFont" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activity_background</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ginger</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

I will give the best answer for any support. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way to customize the font on your check box, follow these steps to change the font:

1-Go to **File/New/Folder/Assets Folder** and create new Assets folser in the default location.

2-Copy your font into your new Assets folder.

3-Use this code inside the onCreate method to set your new font to the check box:

```
    checkBox = findViewById(R.id.skip);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "YourFont.ttf");
    checkBox.setTypeface(font);
```

This is the xml code that I used for the check box, in relative layout:

```
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/skip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:buttonTint="#fff"
    app:buttonTint="#1d1d1b"
    android:text="hello world"
    android:textColor="#1d1d1b"/>
```

But you can change and customize it.

That's the appearance that I got with my custom font:[image]

Comment: It does not work but I give a point as an encouragement :) . The problem is the title and message shows in changed font, but this Checkbox from layout does not. I guess maybe the problem is with the font?

Comment: Make sure you properly import the font to the Assets folder and it's write correctly in the onCreate function, I leave here a tutorial that may help you: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fB17m3kX-go